# Jenkins Groovy Active Choice Reactive Parameter referenced parameter creates error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Okay, so right now I have an Active Choice Parameter, let's call it 'SKU' that is a list of SKUs a user may select from.

I have a Active Choices Reactive Parameter that is referencing the value of SKU and using that value to query files through the GitHub API to generate a list of titles.

When I run my script with a real, but hardcoded, value for the SKU it works.

When I run my script trying to call in the SKU parameter so that it is reactive to what the user originally picks -- using ${SKU} -- it goes to the fallback which I have set to just generate "error":

Groovy script (with hardcoding):

```
token = "value of token"

def command = """
curl -H 'Authorization: token ${token}' -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw" https://api.github.com/repos/org/SKU/path/SKU-File.xml
"""

process = [ 'bash', '-c',  command].execute()

parser = new XmlSlurper()

def rootNode = parser.parseText(process.text)

def count = rootNode.children().size() - 1

titles = []

for (i in 1..count) {
    
    title = rootNode.children()[i].title

    titles += title
}

return titles
```

Note: This works -- with the exception that instead of switching the list of titles depending on the SKU you select, it is always the same list from the hardcoded SKU.

Groovy script (without hardcoding):

```
token = "value of token"

def command = """
curl -H 'Authorization: token ${token}' -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw" https://api.github.com/repos/org/${SKU}/path/${SKU}-File.xml
"""

process = [ 'bash', '-c',  command].execute()

parser = new XmlSlurper()

def rootNode = parser.parseText(process.text)

def count = rootNode.children().size() - 1

titles = []

for (i in 1..count) {
    
    title = rootNode.children()[i].title.toString()

    titles += title
}

return titles
```

Note: This fails and defaults to the Fallback script.
Another important note: This *is* working when I try the script console, however, since the script console is not able to reference the other parameters from my project, I have to harcode in a SKU = "SKU" variable, so not sure it's as equivalent as I'd like it to be.

Fallback script:

```
return ["error"]
```

Note also, I have another Active Choice Reactive Parameter also pointing to the SKU and it *is* working just fine. But in that I'm not calling the SKU in a curl command. I can't quite figure out what's going wrong here, or if I'm referencing something inappropriately.

I've tried converting the ${SKU} parameter to a string as a variable before passing it to the command variable and that didn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the answer:

Not all of my SKUs were accurately pulling titles based on the same criteria as the SKU I was hardcoding.

It's a bit strange that an error on one SKU would pull apart the entire ability to get an accurate list -- e.g. if SKU1 had an error, toggling to SKU2 gave an error *even* if SKU2 was working while hardcoded. I've adjusted my script to work for both SKU1 and SKU2 and now it is working as intended.

This is a 'gotcha' to look out for!